# How to replace NA value of one column with the value coming after that column?

Tags: r

Here is some sample data:

```
dat <- data.frame(col0 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), 
       col1 = c(NA, 100, 100, NA, 200, 200, NA, 300, 300),
       col2 = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3))
```

I would like to change any NA value in col1 when col2 = 1, with the value that succeeds the NA in col1.

The best I can figure out is

```
dat <- dat %>% 
       mutate(col1 = replace(col1, which(is.na(col1) & 
              col2 == 1), 100))
```

But I couldn't figure out how to get the next value of col1...

Ideally, the solution would use tidyverse.

My actual dataset is quite large so a replacing NA in col1 with c(100, 200, 300) would not be an efficient way to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `fill` from the `tidyr` package.

```
library(tidyr)

dat2 <- fill(dat, col1, .direction = "up")
dat2
#   col0 col1 col2
# 1    1  100    1
# 2    1  100    2
# 3    1  100    3
# 4    2  200    1
# 5    2  200    2
# 6    2  200    3
# 7    3  300    1
# 8    3  300    2
# 9    3  300    3
```

Answer (score 1):

An option using `na.locf`

```
library(zoo)
dat$col1 <- na.locf(dat$col1, fromLast = TRUE)
dat$col1
#[1] 100 100 100 200 200 200 300 300 300
```